# Is it legal to use a paper and a pen during Android: Netrunner play?

Tags: android-netrunner

Can one make writings or log during the Android: Netrunner play? Or every player should use only its own memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking notes is not permitted, no.

From the current [Tournament Regulations (v3.2)](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/8d/d6/8dd6ce73-6c74-40ac-a9b5-4c6d4cb50880/adn_tournament_regulations_v32.pdf):

> **Taking Notes and Outside Material**
>
> Players cannot take notes or reference outside material or information during a tournament
> round. However, players may reference official rule documents at any time or ask a judge for
> clarification from official rule documents. Official rule documents include all rules documents
> and inserts available on the Android: Netrunner page of our website, those found in an Android:
> Netrunner product, or any portion thereof.

**Edit**: Under NISEI, this has been relaxed for Casual tier events.

From the current [Organized Play Policies](http://nisei.net/files/Organized_Play_Policies.pdf) document (emphasis mine):

> Taking or referencing notes referring to hidden information or strategy is not permitted at Competitive-level events. Players may reference official rules documents or card text at any time, or ask tournament staff for clarification. **Players may take notes at Casual events**.